# Doctrine migrations keeps generating datetime field over and over again

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I use Symfony 2.1.* with Doctrine 2.3.* and I am having the following problem:

When generating migrations for my mysql (5.5) database, it keeps generating queries for my datetime fields.

My model looks like this:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @var \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"default"=null})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, options={"default"=null})
     */
    private $updatedAt;
}
```

And this is the migration that gets generated every single time:

```
$this->addSql("ALTER TABLE user CHANGE created_at created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE updated_at updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL");
```

It's driving me nuts, since I do a lot of restructuring and every time I have to remove these queries for +/- 15 different entities.

Is this a known issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm just guessing. Having `options={"default"=null}` on a nullable field doens't make sense. If you don't give it a value it's `null` anyway. Try without the option.

Comment: @BetaRide You are right, that works, I guess we had the default assignment to make sure no '0000-00-00' values would be inserted, but without it it just creates a valid migration too. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BetaRide mentions above, you should just remove the `options={"default"=null}`

Comment: I am getting the same issue with datetimetz with no option no nullable...